# I am trying to filter out and match exact text in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, search, filter, match, google-sheets-formula

I have text in a Google Spreadsheet that is the result of a query.
In cell A2, I have a student's name.
In cell B2, I have a list of all of their courses.
For example, B2 may look like:
English I
Math I
World History
PE
Photography 1
(one course per line, all in the same cell)

In column E, I have a list of the courses.
In column F, I need a list of all of the students that have that course in Column B.  I need each list to be in one cell.
For example in E2, it would say English I.  And in F2, it would read:
Student 1
Student 2
Student 3
(one cell, one student per line)

With this formula, I get a list of all students that have that course, but also any where it contains that course.
=IFERROR(if(E2="","",(JOIN( char(10) , FILTER(A:A,search(E2,B:B))))))

So, it returns all the students taking English I, but also all the ones taking English II.

Is there anyway to make it exactly match English I and only English I?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l53sEQHc6SqZW-3ycYVkGtTKaj3ZCJFRk4NXlMQR4xE/edit?usp=sharing. I need it to be formatted like the yellow column on the 'All Recs by Course' Tab.

Edit:
If I pull it in from a different sheet using this formula:
=IFERROR(if(E2="","",(JOIN(char(10),(FILTER(FEED!X:X,search(E2,FEED!V:V)))))))

I seem to be able to pull the right courses, but instead of the cell looking like:
Student 1
Student 2
Student 3
(one cell, one student per line)

It looks like:
Student 1, Student 2, Student 3
(all students in a horizontal list in a single cell - which is how it is on that original sheet).

Thanks in advance,
Beth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in H2

```
=sort(unique(arrayformula(flatten(split(B2:B7,char(10))))))
```

in I2 (drag to the next cells below)

```
=textjoin(char(10),,query(arrayformula(split(flatten(split(B$2:B,char(10))&"~"&A$2:A),"~")),"select Col2 where Col1='"&H2&"' "))
```

[image]

Comment: Almost... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l53sEQHc6SqZW-3ycYVkGtTKaj3ZCJFRk4NXlMQR4xE/edit?usp=sharing. I need it to be more like what's in yellow on the All Recs by Course Tab.

Comment: See my updates answer included in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Hope this fits what you expect!